# The return type 'String?' isn't a 'bool', as required by the closure's context

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I wanted to add this country code to DropdownButton

> Country is my data class.

```
DropdownButton<Country> androdDropDown(BuildContext context) {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<Country>> dropDownItems = [];

    List countryList =
        getAppState(context).counties.where((i) => i.code).toList();

    return DropdownButton<Country>(
      value: countryList.reversed.first,
      items: dropDownItems,
      onChanged: (value) {},
    );
  }
```

the error occurred in `i.code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line:

```
List countryList =
    getAppState(context).counties.where((i) => i.code).toList();
```

You are trying to filter the countries where the code is equal to true. But the variable code is not a boolean but a String?. Try replacing it with:

```
List countryList =
    getAppState(context).counties.where((i) => i.code != null).toList();
```

Comment: Or make a variable with the code you want to filter and make it  i.code == targetCode